# How to perform OR inside PATINDEX

Tags: t-sql, azure-synapse

I'd like to use `PATINDEX` to match any items from a list. If patindex accepted Regex, I'd like to do something like the below:

```
select patindex('% for | is| my%','just for stackoverflow')
```

Obviously this doesn't work and returns 0 for no match. Is there an Or syntax that can be used with LIKE/PATINDEX

Comment: I don't think there is anyway of doing this out of the box, you'd probably need to call `PATINDEX()` once for each search term. If there were multiple matches, which one would you want to be returned by `PATINDEX()`?

Comment: @GarethD I'm not expecting that to occur, so it's not a problem, but first match in the string would be logical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this.

```
SELECT t.SearchString, 
        FirstOccurance = MIN(NULLIF(PATINDEX(ss.value, t.SearchString), 0))
FROM (VALUES('just for stackoverflow'), ('no match')) AS t (SearchString)
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT('%for%|%is%|%my%', '|') AS ss
GROUP BY t.SearchString;
```

It basically passes all your search terms as a single string, splits them and performs the `PATINDEX` once per term and returns the lowest value (excluding 0 which is removed by `NULLIF`)

If your search term isn't a single string, then a better option may be to put them in a table, and perform similar logic using that, e.g.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (SearchTerm NVARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT @T VALUES ('%for%'), ('%is%'), ('%my%');


SELECT t.SearchString, 
        FirstOccurance = (SELECT TOP 1 PATINDEX(ss.SearchTerm, t.SearchString)
                            FROM @T AS ss
                            WHERE PATINDEX(ss.SearchTerm, t.SearchString) > 0
                            ORDER BY PATINDEX(ss.SearchTerm, t.SearchString))
FROM (VALUES('just for stackoverflow'), ('no match')) AS t (SearchString);
```

I've used a slightly different technique (TOP 1 in a correlated sub-query rather than `CROSS APPLY` with `MIN`) for no particular reason, just to show that there is more than one way to approach it.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using Azure Synapse Analytics, and if you need RegEx capabilities then you can get them using Synapse Notebooks.  One pattern I am using is where something is not possible in conventional SQL then copy the data over to Spark, process it and then put it back.  This is the pattern:

[image: Synapse Notebook Pattern]

As there is an overhead to copying the data over, a duplicate cost in the running the Spark pool, potentially a warm-up time of a couple of minutes for the pool it has to be 'worth it' so I reserve this pattern for things that are not possible in conventional SQL or there is a specific need or a proven performance benefit.

A sample dataframe:

[image: dataframe]

A simple example in Scala:

```
// Get the data from the dedicated SQL pool
val df = spark.read.synapsesql("someDb.dbo.someTable")

// Add the new columns, and remove any unnecessary ones
val df2 = df.
    withColumn("for_or_in", regexp_extract($"errorMessage", "for|in", 0)).
    withColumn("for_or_in_with_word_boundary", regexp_extract($"errorMessage", "\\bfor\\b|\\bin\\b", 0)).
    drop("errorMessage")

// Write the dataframe back to the dedicated SQL pool
df2.write.synapsesql("someDb.dbo.someTable_processed", Constants.INTERNAL)

// Debugging
//df2.show
```

You can see naïve checks show 'in' occurring in 'mainly' which you may or may not want.  I get round it here using the word boundary RegEx token `\b`.

If you feel more comfortable with Spark SQL then you can use that too to create the dataframe:

```
val df2 = spark.sql("""
SELECT *,
    regexp_extract(errorMessage, "for|in", 0) for_or_in,
    regexp_extract(errorMessage, "\\bfor\\b|\\bin\\b", 0) for_or_in_with_word_boundary,

    locate(" for ", errorMessage) locate1,
    locate("in ", errorMessage) locate2
    
FROM errorMessages
""")
```

The results:

[image: results]

Comment: Probably would take a bit of engineering to add in the middle of my SQL process, but well worth knowing that a spark environment can be had on demand for tasks less suited to SQL!

Answer (score 0):

If I wasn't using Azure Synapse/SQL DW/SQL Pools (other brand names for it may also exist) then the code soup below would work as an alternative

```
select  GREATEST  (patindex ('% for %', objectname),patindex ('% is %', objectname),patindex ('% my %', objectname)) from myTable
```